# Problem with merging accounts

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, email, merge-accounts

I have this account under an email that I ask this question from right now AND I have an old account here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18993/nikolajk

that I made under an old email address. I want to get rid of the old address.

I repeated the merging process and confirm the 2 mails several times now, but it doesn't seem to work.

What's suspicious is also that the two numbers below (476... and 932...) are not 18993, even if I entered 18993 in the form all four times I went through it.

Comment: Did you confirm from the emails of both accounts or just from this one (that you used to post here)?

Comment: If you go to the account you link to and hit "Network Profile" to the top right of the profile page, you go to this url: `http://stackexchange.com/users/932368/nikolajk` That's that account's _network_ user id, not the math site's user id. Likewise, your current account's link is `http://stackexchange.com/users/4764295/nikolajk`, so the ids do match up. Also, are you aware you need to confirm on _both_ accounts through their related email addresses? You'll need to straight contact the team since you can't access one account. (Assumed from "email address I got rid of.")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

18993 is your user ID on Mathematics. The email always lists your main stackexchange.com profile for the merge procedure, *not* a per-site profile, which will use your network account ID that will pretty much never be the same as an on-site user ID.

I'm confused what exactly you're getting caught up on, though. Are you only clicking *that* link? There are two separate emails you need to verify, one gets sent to the email address for each account. You need to click *both* of them in order to confirm the merge. If you don't have access to one of the email addresses anymore in order to retrieve the second email, then you'll need to use the [contact](/contact) form and use the other option to get a hold of a human to do the merge manually. You cannot complete the merge yourself with access to only one email.

---

This wasn't immediately obvious to me, but your merge is failing because one of your accounts has profiles on it that are considered high-reputation. We don't allow the normal merge process to complete in this case, and after confirming the first time your request was dumped into a queue that only gets checked once a day in most cases. I've approved your merge and you should be good to go.